# Installing an exhaust fan to attic to cool house

Tags: exhaust-fan, ventilation, cooling

No AC in house, No option to get one. I've been getting by with the usual tricks, but I think I may be onto a good idea and I'd appreciate some vetting. My attic has a drop tile entry, and I am thinking of building a new drop tile with either an exhaust fan mated to it, or ducted to it. My idea is that I can turn on the fan with a smart plug and outlet in the attic, open my downstairs windows at night, and pull cool air up and into the house. In the winter, I will be going back to the existing drop tile. House has about 15k CF, so I can turn over about once per hour with a 290 CFM fan. My question is, will the ventilated soffits be too much restriction to actually get the rated CFM? Will I need a more powerful exhaust fan to notice a difference? Is this a terrible idea?

Comment: Websearch "whole house fan". It's a thing. The commercial versions include dampers and ducts so they mostly seal themselves in colder weather.

Comment: One of my best friends in college had this in the place he rented waaaay back in college in the 80s. It's not a new concept, don't reinvent it.

Answer (score 1):

Its an idea that works.

There are whole businesses dedicated to this concept.

You can also buy kits in hardware stores.  They come in various capacities with all the bits including a thermostat and summer/winter mode switch.  They go under various names `heat transfer kits` and `home ventilation kits`.